# How to give input to Visual Studio Code user defined code snippets before triggering

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, autosuggest

I am aware of how to make code snippets in VSCode. For example, to build a 1-d array, I have defined a code snippet as shown below-

```json
"Create a 1-dimensional Array": {
        "prefix": "darr",
        "body": [
            "${1:Type}[] ${2:name} = new ${1:Type}[${3:Size}];",
            "$4"
        ],
        "description": "Creating a 1-dimensional Array"
    }
```

Which is working perfectly fine. But here something is slowing down my productivity as I have to give array type, name and its size by pressing tab again and again to this snippet after triggering.

Is it possible to give these details to the vscode user defined snippet before triggering it? For example -
If I write booleanarr10, then it will create a code as - `boolean[] arr = new boolean[10];`
Or If I write intarr50, then it will create a code as - `int[] arr = new int[50];`

Even an extension that can do it is fine for me.
Please suggest.

Comment: use extension Hypersnips with regex prefix

Comment: Thanks @rioV8. Could you please suggest an example. I am not able to understand from the extension details.

Comment: hi @rioV8, Please help with one example of using Hypersnips in java.